# Error in overriding onRecieve() while making android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, overriding

I have  a AppWidget Class (extends AppWidgetProvider).

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {    
        @Override   
        public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent){
                  //do something
            } 
}
```

I am receiving an error as

> The method onRecieve(Context, Intent) of type AppWidget must override or implement a supertype method

with a quick fix of removing @Override.

Why can not I override the method. How else can I do the same thing.??

Comment: it just only spelling mistake..

Comment: will have to wait 5 min... :) cannot accept answers within 5 mins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your

```
@Override   
public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent){
              //do something
}
```

to

```
@Override   
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
              //do something
 }
```

it solve your problem..